# Extract a word and `n` characters after it from a line?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to extract the JIRA Ticket number from a string.

The Jira ticket might be mentioned any where in the line like:

1. Merge pull request #1387 from Config-change/**REL-12345**
2. **REL-12345**: Enable XAPI at config level

I just want **REL-12345** as the output.

Comment: Is `REL` the keyword you're trying to find?  Or do you want any pattern matching 3 letters a dash and 5 numbers?

Comment: N characters?  Do you want to match `REL-364` and `REL-357465`?  How do you know that all of your tickets are 5 digits?  Do you simply not care about older tickets?  Seems easier to match `[0-9]+` than "n characters"

Comment: Hi Mat, REL is the pattern I am trying to find. Thanks

Comment: Hi William, This automation only applies to the newly opened JIRA tickets. So, there is no need for the older tickets with 4 digits. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -Eow 'REL-[0-9]+'
```

`+` is one or more, to specifiy N numbers (eg 5):

```
grep -Eow 'REL-[0-9]{5}
```

- Ranges: `{3,6}` is 3 to 6, `{5,}` is 5 or more, etc.
- On GNU/Linux: `man grep -> /Repetition` for more details.
- `-o` prints only matching strings
- `-w` matches full words only, ie. to avoid matching `WREL-12345` (for example)
- `grep -Eow 'REL-[[:alnum:]]+'` for both letters and numbers (after `REL-`).

Answer (score 0):

If this is the standard.....

Input: *Merge pull request #1387 from Config-change/REL-12345*

```
echo "Merge pull request #1387 from Config-change/REL-12345" | cut -d/ -f2
```

Input: *REL-12345: Enable XAPI at config level*

```
 echo "REL-12345: Enable XAPI at config level" | cut -d: -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a String to `sed` and use substitution with REGEX, like this:

```
myString="This is REL-12345 a test string "
sed -n 's/.*\(\REL-5*[0-9]*\).*/\1/p' <<< $myString
```

this should return: `REL-12345`

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
$ cat jira.dat
Merge pull request #1387 from Config-change/REL-12345
REL-12346: Enable XAPI at config level
```

One idea using `bash` regex matching and the resulting `BASH_REMATCH[]`:

```
regex='(REL-[[:digit:]]+)'

while read -r line
do
    printf "\n########## ${line}\n"
    [[ "${line}" =~ ${regex} ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < jira.dat
```

This generates:

```
REL-12345
REL-12346
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample data:

```
$ cat jira.dat
Merge pull request #1387 from Config-change/REL-12345
REL-12346: Enable XAPI at config level
```

One idea using `grep`:

```
$ grep -Eo 'REL-[[:digit:]]+' jira.dat
REL-12345
REL-12346
```